# How to get values from one table with condition on another table in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables, **Asset Population** and **Heavy Machines or Engines**

**Asset Population:**

| Customer Number | Product Family |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Aedium Dheel Aoaders |
| 02 | Aedium Arack Aype Aractors |
| 03 | Aarge Dheel Aoaders |
| 04 | Aotor Araders |
| .. | .. |
| 90 | Arack Aype Aoaders |

**Heavy Machines or Engines:**

| Product Family | Heavy Machines or Engines |
| --- | --- |
| Aedium Dheel Aoaders | Heavy Machines |
| Aedium Arack Aype Aractors | Heavy Machines |
| Aarge Dheel Aoaders | Heavy Machines |
| .. | .. |
| Clympian | Engines |

Both the tables have **many-to-many** relationship on the common column **Product Family**.

There are few customers which have both Heavy Machines and Engines.

**I want to get the list of customers who has only Engines and no Heavy Machines.**

My take on this:

```
Customers = 
CALCULATETABLE('Asset population',
DISTINCT('Asset population'[Customer Number]),
'Heavy Machine or Engine reference'[Heavy Machines or Engines]<>"Heavy Machines"
)
```

But this is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Test this Code, and let me know. I tested it with some fake data with the relationship like you indicated (many-many), and It run without any problem.

```
Customers = 
VAR Engines = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Asset Population'[Customer Number]),
    'Heavy Machines or Engines'[Heavy Machines or Engines] = "Engines")
VAR HeavyMachines = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Asset Population'[Customer Number]),
    'Heavy Machines or Engines'[Heavy Machines or Engines] = "Heavy Machines")
    RETURN
    EXCEPT(Engines,HeavyMachines)
```

Comment: What would be the code if the condition added =  get the list of customers who has only Engines or Others and has no Heavy Machines

Comment: Then change only the first VAR Engines statement by adding IN {"Engines", "Others"} instead of (= "Engines")

Comment: Can you solve this - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EgtnrFqZ38k_ReScJNFBH0jgtqAdhSfs/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111786840706330555618&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: This is not a platform to solve somebody's problem. You will solve it , and I will only guide you in the right direction. I advice you to make some efforts, and try to solve it. Share your work , Then ask for advise.

Comment: If you are doing assessment, I can't help you. You need to pass it deservedly. If you need training, then that's entirely different thing. Passing an assessment will not make you Power BI hero. You need to master the basics. I need to repeat : master the basics: You can contact me on LinkedIn . I shared it on my profile page.

Comment: You are are being judgmental. I am not a student trying to complete his assignment. Even I am a working professional, just got stuck somewhere which everyone gets. Asked a help, not sermon Mr. Power BI Hero.